# Dell 7530, not start OS without PS connected

Tags: dell

I format the Dell 7530 with W10, for install ubuntu 19.10.
After the update of dicember 2019 of the bios from DELL, the operation system not start if the laptop is not connected to the Power supply.
I execute the ubuntu update to 20.04 and update the bios Dell in May 2020; but the problem is not solved.
Someone have the solution?
Thanks

Comment: You mention both Ubuntu 19.10 & update to 10.04?  Did you mean 20.04? as 10.04 is over a decade old & well out of it's support life.

Comment: Perhaps some troubleshooting help here: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Laptop-won-t-turn-on-without-being-plugged-in/td-p/5167175

Comment: Thankas, but I try to do this check and anything is ok.
Also Dell support help me to check, but at the end no give me a solution